# How to separate variadic template arguments while printing to the standard output inside a function

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename ...T>
void print(T ...args)
{
    (std::cout << ... << args);
}

int main()
{
    print(1, 2.5, 3, "Hello, world!");
}
```

Output: `12.53Hello, world!`

I want the output to be `1 2.5 3 Hello, World!`, any help would be appreciated

Comment: `((std::cout << args << " "), ...);`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: That would print an extra space at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might do:

```
template <typename ... Ts>
void print(const Ts& ... args)
{
    [[maybe_unused]]const char* sep = "";
    (((std::cout << sep << args), sep = " "), ...);
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a8133a9244b6b5af)

Answer (score 0):

Based on Igor's comment (without printing extra space):

```
template <class T, class ...Ts>
void printA(T arg, Ts ...args) {
  std::cout << arg;
  ((std::cout << ' ' << args), ...);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't handle empty pack :)